# Is a PayPal preapproval guaranteed?

Tags: paypal

PayPal offers the option to preapprove an account. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/

Is this feature like a credit card authorization, that I can authorize the amount of money on ANY PayPal account (that books via our website) and then I can withdraw the money whenever I want (I would withdraw it 3 days if my background-check on the client was OK).

Looking forward to your replies.